# How to enable Wayland in Pop!_OS 21.10?

Tags: xorg, wayland, pop-os

I am currently using Pop!_OS 21.10. Pop!_OS always defaults itself to Xorg. How can I enable Wayland in this distro. Because I want to try Wayland, its speed and touchpad gestures with GNOME 40.

Please help

Comment: google searched "wayland in pop os" and [this was one of many results](https://community.frame.work/t/framework-and-popos/2898/18)

Answer (score 3):

Got to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and set `WaylandEnable=true` then run `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` in terminal.